# gsutil rsync process running infinite time

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am using gsutil command line tool. I am using 'gsutil -m rsync -  . The Source is an Amazon S3 Path and Destination is Google storage. I am running a shell script scheduling via a crontab. And before uploading the S3 and GS path, I am removing all the data from GS.
   For lot of cronjobs I can see in waiting state for more than a week/month. The jobs are sending warning messages that the downloaded data cannot be checked for the integrity and then it is waiting for infinite amount of time. Is there any bug related to this gsutil 'rsync'.
The gsutil version: 4.9

Comment: I see a similar problem when syncing from local fs to gs. When I control-C after waiting for a long while, I can see that not all of the python threads started by the process die. I have to kill -9 them.

Comment: Yeah James, I faced same issue. I have reported to gs-team in google about the issue. Hopefully, they will come up with the solution in next releases.

Comment: I think in my case it is related to fifos or sockets that happen to be in the path. I need test more.